# Git post-receive hook loop though all commits

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

I am trying to do a post-receive hook on server side that will run some Python script once for each commit in push.

I have a loop:

```
while read oldrev newrev refname
do
    python /local/Git/util.py $newrev $oldrev $refname
done
```

But this runs script only for last commit that was given in push.

**There is any way to run script for all commits pushed to the server in one push?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In scripts, use `git rev-list` to obtain the SHA-1s of commits in a range. In this case you should loop over the output from `git rev-list $oldrev..$newrev`, e.g. like this:

```
git rev-list $oldrev..$newrev | while read rev ; do
    python /local/Git/util.py $rev $oldrev $refname
done
```

Comment: Simply and clever! Thanks man a lot. Hope you will get tons of presents from Santa!